# Java Program to split the array based on marks

Tags: java, character, string, arrays

Create class Student with below attributes:
rollNo
Name
Marks

Create class StudentDemo with main method. Declare array of 5 student objects in main method. Initialize this array. Declare another method in this class – splitStudentArray. This method will take the student array and a character as input parameters. If the input character is ‘o’ this method will return array of students with odd value of marks. If the input character is ‘e’ then this method will return array of students with even value or marks. It will return null array if there is any other character specified. Display name and marks for this returned array from main method.

i have made the program but it is returning the reference of an array.

Solution:
package assignment2;

public class StudentDemo {

```
public static void main(String[] args) 

{
    Student[] st=new Student[5];
    Student st1=new Student(1, "abhi", 200.5);
    Student st2=new Student(2, "maggie", 200);
    Student st3=new Student(3, "suraj", 107);
    Student st4=new Student(4, "naveen", 249);
    Student st5=new Student(5, "jajan",100 );

    Student[] sts = {st1,st2,st3,st4,st5}; 
    System.out.println("splitStudentArray : " + splitStudentArray(sts, 'o'));
}

public static Student[] splitStudentArray(Student[] sts, char ch)
{
    int Marks = 0;
    if (ch=='o' && Marks == 1 || Marks==3 || Marks==5)
    {
    System.out.println("number is odd");
    }

    if (ch=='e'&& Marks == 2 || Marks==4 )
    {
     System.out.println("number is even");
    }
    return sts ;

}
```

}

class Student
{
    private int rollNo;
    private String Name;
    private double Marks;

```
public Student(int rollNo, String name, double marks) 
{

    this.rollNo = rollNo;
    this.Name = name;
    this.Marks = marks;
}


public double getMarks() {
    return Marks;
}


public void setMarks(double marks) {
    Marks = marks;
}


public int getRollNo() {
    return rollNo;
}


public String getName() {
    return Name;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First of all, shouldn't this be on stackOverflow rather than here?

Secondly - if I understand what you're trying to do correctly, in your splitStudentArray(...) you should do something like:

```
 ArrayList<Students> helper = new ArrayList<>();
 int j = 0;
   for(int i; i < sts.length; i++){
      if(checkIfOdd(sts[i]) == true){
      helper[j] = sts[i]
      j++;
   }
```

and then you return helper instead of sts.

Cheers

Comment: Kindly give suggestion without using array list

Comment: Sure, I'm going to edit my post when I have some spare time.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in "sts" and returning the same thing you are passing in "sts". You are giving a method an apple just to get an apple. Just keep the apple. No. What do you want back, is what you should give back. You are only returning "sts". If you want to return something, then return something instead of just printing to the screen.

```
/**
*   Hint!
*   EVEN: using modulus:  if mynumber%2==0
*   This could be useful in returning ODD and EVEN arrays too.
*
*   @param1 ...
*   @param2 ...
*   @param3 ...
**/
public static Student[] splitStudentArray(Student[] sts, char ch)
{
    int Marks = 0;
    if (ch=='o' && Marks == 1 || Marks==3 || Marks==5)
    {
      System.out.println("number is odd");
      //return oddArray(str)  create function or insert for loop here
    }
    else if (ch=='e'&& Marks == 2 || Marks==4 )
    {
      System.out.println("number is even");
      //return evenArray(str) create function or insert for loop here
    }
    else
      return null;
}
```